# Where can i find "numbers" about bounce rate statistics in mobile application?

Tags: user-behavior, mobile-application, statistics

I am about to offer my boss two user registration funnels.
One that the user must validate their phone number before they can use the app (something my boss prefer) and the other let the user use the app with the option to validate their phone and get something in return.

Before I send him those two offers, I wish to add some supportive details about each funnel. Anyone know a good source?

Comment: Google Analytics can tell you that if you set it up first & there are several other analytics tools for iOS & Android (the names escape me - sorry). Question: Why would you expect users to give you & validate a phone # when they haven't even been able to use the app first to determine its usefulness? Most people hate to even give a real email address & nobody likes giving away personal info for nothing. I don't have sources to back it up, but to me that sounds like a surefire route to a bunch of 1-star ratings...

Answer (score 1):

Your question has at least 2 angles:

1. [App download strategy](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile%20app%20download%20strategy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=coSyVY7WL8uQwgTGlKGwCw)
2. Analytics over strategy (or [App Acquisition](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2568794?hl=en) based on strategy)

Keep in mind these are very basic angles, there are more, the more granularity, the better.

Now, if you take a look to the link on the first angle (just a Google search), you'll find lots of results on STRATEGY. None of them (well, at least the first 3-4 pages) suggests your first approach, because most people won't do what you want. Simple as that. Besides, if you offer this from Google or iOs marketplaces, I really doubt they'll let you run with it. Not to mention **your phone is validated on download**, so why are you asking for a second validation? I don't know your reasons, but most people will think *"they want to spam me"* and abort download process. Specially because your approach already exists and is the basis for spam applications and bogus charges (I'm not saying this is your case, just mentioning what users will perceive since they're used to this kind of tricks)

So, you need to think things and plan an strategy where your goal (app download) is accomplished. Once you get your plan in place, you can study user behavior and adjust things accordingly. To do this, you have several tools. If you use the above mentioned marketplaces, then you have app acquisition analytics, but it's always useful to read Google's [App Acquisition](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2568794?hl=en) page so you understand the basics.

There are many other tracking tools as well, but with the provided links I think you'll have enough to understand the process and give your boss a quite detailed plan of action with backed up reasoning

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about recording detailed usage statistics from within your mobile app, you can try and implement Google Analytics into it. I heard from a colleague at work that it is possible. Should work just like on a website.

Comment: thanks! i was looking for existing details so it could help me favorite one of the two options.

Answer (score 0):

[Google analytics](http://www.google.it/intl/it/analytics/index.html) is the best tracker for that. I used it many time to compare the performance of different interface / interaction.

It has a section dedicate for mobile app, if you use native app.

Some information are in real time, other scheduled every 24h.